# Excel VBA--Would like to minimize a built-in dialog box

Tags: vba, excel, dialog, outlook

**tl,dr:** Can I make the Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show dialog box minimize-able?

**The Procedure:** I have a solution that automatically creates a file, compiles an email and attaches the file.  The user can review and choose to send the email or close without sending.

**The Problem:** The problem is that some users would like to copy/paste content into the body of the auto-compiled email.  This is not possible for two reasons:

- The routine that compiles the email uses the clipboard.
- The dialog box does not allow the user to minimize (so they can copy the content after the email is compiled).

**Potential Solutions:**

- Don't use the clipboard during the email compilation.  I'd rather not do this because it would require a moderate sized reworking of the code.
- Invoke the Outlook Object Library to create an email that way.  I'd rather not because this tool is distributed to about 110 people with varying versions of Excel and Outlook and (Outlook Library) compatibility issues would be rampant.
- Manage the clipboard after the email compilation routine to make the last user-created 'copy' active again.  This solution seems viable but not ideal.
- Allow the built-in dialog box to be modal/minimize-able so the user can copy their content post-compilation.  *This solution seems best.*

Any answers/ideas/guidance are much appreciated!

Comment: `with varying versions of Excel and Outlook and (Outlook Library) compatibility issues would be rampant.` Not if you use Late Binding :)

Comment: BTW, I can't suggest you any code enhancements as I am not sure how are you using `Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail)` in your code. You have nicely explained your question. If you include some code with it, then this could be classified as a "very well asked question" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Minimize button doesn't make sense for the SendMail dialog, as this dialog is modal - i.e. it must be closed before you can continue working in Excel. Furthermore this Excel dialog object is defined inside a lib and not easily accessible for modification through VBA.

Workaround for your users is to instruct them to copy text into the clipboard buffer BEFORE the dialog is opened. Unless your application destroys the clipboard on creating the mail body, this would be available for pasting.

If you need the clipboard content in your routine, you can first read out the current content into a text variable and restore this to the clipboard on exit.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The routine does indeed use the clipboard, voiding the user's copy.  Users wish to copy several formatted paragraphs (an explanation of their data) and so copying into a simple text variable is not viable.  Copying the user's clipboard content to a separate (late bound) word doc is possible but would at the same time constitute the second listed potential solution.

Answer (score -1):

first idea is to manupulate with .parent, but i don't know if it's possible. Second idea is to open another instance of Excel and call Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail) from there, then user will be able to switch to first excel window. but you have to close second excel instance when email will be sent or closed.